# SQL Server Syntax, Multiple SELECT COUNT(columnA) WHERE (columnA=difvalue) in same query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was wondering if I could combine multiple `count(columnA) FROM TABLE_A WHERE columnB = 'difvalue'` into one query with the PK being `NULL` for some counts.

What I came up with that is completely broken.

```
SELECT 
    One.ColumnOne, One.PKOne, Two.ColumnOne, Two.PkTwo 
FROM
    (SELECT  
         COUNT(pk) AS PKOne, columnone
     FROM
         Film 
     WHERE 
         columntwo = 'FM1'
     GROUP BY 
         columnone) AS one, 
    (SELECT 
         COUNT(pk) AS PKTwo, columnone
     FROM
         Film 
     WHERE 
         columntwo = 'FM2'
     GROUP BY 
         columnone) AS two
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expected results here please?

Comment: It was solved by fa06. Thanks though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation

```
SELECT columnone,
COUNT(case when columntwo = 'FM1' then pk end) AS PKOne,
COUNT(case when columntwo = 'FM2' then pk end) AS PKTwo
From Film 
GROUP BY columnone
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect. Thanks so much... I'm so new to sql I'll have to look this one up. I reppd.

Comment: sorry I never used stack overflow before! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

use case when

```
select columnone,
sum(case when columntwo = 'FM1' then 1 else 0 end) AS PKOne,
sum(case when columntwo = 'FM2' then 1 else 0 end) AS PKtwo    
From Film     
GROUP BY columnone
```